# Handle cross domain issue in angular 4 with external API

Tags: ajax, angular, angular-httpclient

I am using **Postal PIN Code API** for getting Post Office(s) details search by Postal PIN Code in angular 5 application. Below is the url of the external API :

**http://postalpincode.in/api/pincode/{**PINCODE**}**

I am issuing a GET request from the application but it is giving me below error :

> **No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access**

Although this request is working perfectly fine from browser and postman. I understand that we need to configure our server with cross-domain policies for accepting cross-domain request but this is an external API and I don't have control over it. How can I resolve this issue?

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: Have you made use of any interceptors?

Comment: @Nitheesh : Interceptors in GET request ? Pl explain more what kind of intrerceptors.

Answer (score 0):

Best: CORS header (requires server changes) CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) is a way for the server to say “I will accept your request, even though you came from a different origin.” This requires cooperation from the server – so if you can’t modify the server (e.g. if you’re using an external API), this approach won’t work.

Modify the server to add the header Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * to enable cross-origin requests from anywhere (or specify a domain instead of *). This should solve your problem.

2nd choice: Proxy Server If you can’t modify the server, you can run your own proxy. And this proxy can return the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header if it’s not at the Same Origin as your page.

Instead of sending API requests to some remote server, you’ll make requests to your proxy, which will forward them to the remote server.

Here are a few proxy options.

Ref: https://daveceddia.com/access-control-allow-origin-cors-errors-in-angular/

Comment: Thnx. Let me try this and get back to you.

Comment: currently your localhost is not secured http requesting https so it's showing the error if you deploy the code in some sever or try to change your local http connection https check this  https://brianflove.com/2016/10/22/angular-cli-using-https/